# How to save a new record for Location when creating a new Event in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, belongs-to

**See solution below**

So I have two models, in which an Event belongs to a certain Location. Since I'm not planning on building management for Locations, I would like the user to either choose an existing Location or provide him with a text field to create a new location on the fly. I understand that something needs to be done to handle this on save (or in a before filter for instance), but my search didn't result in a solution due to a lack of knowledge for relevant search terms (what is this pattern called?)

Any way, some relevant code:

```
#location.rb, does not have a controller
class Location < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :events
end

#event.rb
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :location, inverse_of: :events
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :location
end
```

I've found some information about using `inverse_of:` and `accept_nested_attributes_for` to be able to create a form, but the following view for /events/new does not show any fields:

```
.row
  = form_for @event, html: { multipart: true } do |f|
  .col-sm-8
    .panel-heading
      .panel-title Add / Edit Event 
    .panel-body
      = render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object if @event.errors.any?
      .actions
        = f.label :title
        = f.text_field :title

        #this generates the select for location
        = f.label :location_id
        = f.collection_select(:location_id, Location.all, :id, :title, prompt: "Please select or create a new location by completing the form below")

        #this *should* generate a form for the location, but doesn't
        = f.fields_for :location do |location| 
          = location.label :title
          = location.text_field :title
```

Any thoughts on getting this to work and saving related model?

Upon request, the very simple create and new methods for the event_controller

```
  def new
    @event = Event.new
  end

  def create
    @event = current_user.events.build(event_params)
    if @event.save
      flash[:success] = "Event created!"
      redirect_to events_path
    else
      render :new
    end
  end
```

**EDIT, a bit further**

Ok, a little but further now. I have the form showing when I add the following to my new method:

```
  def new
    @event = Event.new
    @location = @event.build_location
  end
```

And adapting the call to the form helper like this:

```
        = f.fields_for :location, @location do |location|
          = location.label :title
          = location.text_field :title
```

But I have no clue how to adapt the create action, so that it:

- saves the location_id if it's set
- saves a new location if it isn't
- also respects the validation rules (and shows them) in the form
- updates / saves the event with the correct (new) location_id

Thanks.

**Solution, had to address the parameters differently**

So I played around in console and discovered that you can save the related model in one save command. Only prerequisite seems to be that you call the params in a different manner:

```
def create
  @event = current_user.events.build(event_params)
  if @event.save
    flash[:success] = "Event created!"
    redirect_to events_path
  else
    render :new
  end
end

private
  def event_params
    params.require(:event).permit(:title, :content, :start_date, :end_date, :location_id, location_attributes: [:title])
  end
```

Comment: can you show your events_controller as well?. Most probably you need to build you location, @event.build_location

Comment: I've updated my code